# how to connect QuickBooks Multiple accounts in my QuickBooks App using only Email and Password for manage clients accounts

Tags: quickbooks, account

I am building a website and I need to allow the user to come on my site and let them add and connect their accounts only using email and password after that I can pull all his account data from QuickBooks and can manage it on my site. But I am not getting an API to allow me to connect the multiple accounts to connect without their Client ID and Secret Keys.

I have created a QuickBooks App and created an account in the App by Configuring the created account's Client ID, Secret key, and redirect URL in the project environment I was able to connect the QuickBooks account on my site, and by calling APIs I got the desired data. But I am not able to get data on another person's account on my website because for getting the other person's account data I need to use and configure its account Client and secret key which I don't have. So anyone can tell me what should I do? or which API I can use for this purpose? The Xenett website allows the same process but I am not able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks apps don't work like that.  They have to add your app to their QB, which requires they log into their QB account and approve the connection.  Once they approve the connection then your app can query their data.  A QB user should never have to give you their secret.